# Retrofit2 in Android Fragment how to implement correctly?

Tags: android, android-fragments, retrofit2

I'm using Retrofit 2 to consume an API. I have a service (interface) which returns a list:

```
@GET("atenciones")
Call<List<Atencion>> getAtenciones(@Query("medico_id") int id, @Query("date1") String date1, @Query("date2") String date2)
```

Where should I do the request? In the `MainActivity` which contains the `Fragment` and send the result list using `Bundle`? or should do the request in the Fragment? this is a list not a single object. Which is the correct way?

## Edit

Try to call retrofit in Fragment, this is my code:

```
public class FragmentRendicion extends Fragment {

private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
View rootView;
APIService api;

public FragmentRendicion() {
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rendicion, container, false);
    api= ApiUtils.getAPIService();
        getAtenciones();
    return rootView;
}

private void getAtenciones() {
//using static parameters
    Call<List<Atencion>> call= api.getAtenciones(293,"2014-10-13","2014-10-13");
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Atencion>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Atencion>> call, Response<List<Atencion>> response) {
            System.out.println("estamos aquiiii "+response.message());
            List<Atencion> atenciones= response.body();
            layoutManager= new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            RecyclerView recycler= (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.rvRendicion);
            recycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            RvRendicionAdapter rvAdapter= new RvRendicionAdapter(atenciones);
            recycler.setAdapter(rvAdapter);


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Atencion>> call, Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("FALLOOOOO:  "+t.getMessage());//HERE RETUNRS NULL
        }
    });

}
}
```

Can someone tell me is if it correct way to call retrofit2 in fragment?

Comment: Rotate your screen and see what happen :D

Comment: You need to handle configuration change. Apart from that it looks alright. You should check the new architecture components sample by google the github sample should give you an insight for how to architecture and also give you an hint to where to call your web service

Comment: @Raghunandan You are right. There are too many things to cover this question: Fragment life cycle, Retrofit implementation, Configuration change, architecture... This link could help matQ  get these stuff in general https://guides.codepath.com/android/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit and https://guides.codepath.com/android/Creating-and-Using-Fragments

Comment: thanks guys! using postman with the same parameters shows me all the records, but in my Geny Motion emulator not (using the API to login works perfect) it shows me null, this is the output:

    E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
    E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
    I/System.out: FALLOOOOO:  null
   Application terminated.

Comment: it get in the on Failure way.. why? any suggestion? output doesn't show other error. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the structure of your code but since you are using fragments my best guess is you should do it in the `Fragment`.

In the `onResponseOK` of the Retrofit call you will have something like this:

```
@Override
public void onResponseOK(Response<List<Atencion>> response) {
    ...
    //access data here
}
```

In the `callback` you get your list. Pass the list to the adapter of your (I suppose) `Recycler/Listview.` Access the list like this:

```
List<Atencion> myList = response.body();
```

Comment: Your code seems correct! If the callback returns in onFailure() try to do `t.printStackTrace()` and check the error it returns. `t.getMessage()` often returns null.